# Nativescript and resources folder - is there a simple solution?

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

> I will start with the fact that currently -  *I'm uploading successfully*
>   an mp3 file to a server - **but** via a hacky way.

I'm having 2 `raw` folders as you can see :

[image]

And here is the working code to upload the file :

```
 upload1()
    {

        let file = fs.path.join(fs.knownFolders.currentApp().path, "raw/a1.mp3");

        var request = {
            url:         "http://posttestserver.com/post.php",
            method:      "POST",
            ...
        };

        var task = session.uploadFile(file, request);
        task.on("progress", this.logEvent);

    }
```

[*Here is the output for the successful upload (showing progress)*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFohh.png)

**So where is the problem ?**

The current file is being uploaded from the root `raw` folder. ([proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtnNW.png))

But the right way ([*as I was told*](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/folder-location-problem/3304/4?u=royi_namir))is to upload it via the `raw` folder or the `assets` folder and then reference it via  `res://raw/a1.mp3` ( or `res://raw/a1`).

So I've switched to :  `let file="res://raw/a1.mp3";`

But got an [*error*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSnEc.png):

> ERROR Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file at
>   path: res://raw/a1.mp3

Also for : `let file="res://raw/a1"; //without extension` - Got an error :

> JS: ERROR Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file at
>   path: res://raw/a1

**Question:**
How can I access the mp3 file under the `raw` folder? (not the outside folder but the resource one)

Comment: Why do you need to upload a file packages within you apk? You already have access to the file so why not put it on you file server directly?

Comment: @WadeWilson I'm still learning the material. At the end - I want to upload a file which is found at the raw folder. For now - please treat it as an APP that generates mp3 and saves it in `RAW` folder - and needs to upload it to the server.

Comment: I've added an answer that should help at least point you in the right direction. The raw folder and all folders under the res directory are read only so you won't be able to write to them which makes since given how the android build system works with resources. You will need to store the generated mp3s directly to the devices storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unfamiliar with NativeScript but here is an example of how to access the raw folder files regardless of type using Java:

```
public static final FileDescriptor getFDForResource(Context context, int resId) {
     AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(resId);
     if (afd != null) {
        return afd.getFileDescriptor();
     }
     return null;
}

public void readFile(int resId) {
    FileDescriptor fd = getFDForResource(resId);
    InputStream inputStream
    if(fd != null) {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(fd);
        byte nextByte;
        while((nextByte = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
            // Upload the file bytes to your server.
        }
    }
}
```

You'll wanna place this code in a Util class and access it using NativeScript. I'm sure there is some API to do such a thing but being I am unfamiliar that is all I can provide.

Comment: Please note that in order to get the resId of the raw resource, you will first want to make a call to `getIdentifier` - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) by passing a string like `com.myapp.Name:raw/a1.mp3`, followed by nulls for the optional parameters.