# RAW files (audio) folder in Nativescript

Tags: android, notifications, nativescript

Is the `raw` folder automatically considered by NativeScript when packaging the app?

I could not find any reference to this. So what I'm trying to do is to store a .mp3 file in that folder and use it then as a custom notification sound.

The problem is: 
How can I then reference that file? What should I write as a path? Here's the concerned code:

```
// how should my path be like here?
const sound = android.net.Uri.fromFile(new java.io.File('path????'));

const notification = notificationBuilder
    .setSmallIcon(ad.resources.getDrawableId('icon'))
    .setContentTitle('Some test notification')
    .setContentText('Done with native builder')
    .setPriority(2)
    .setSound() 
    .setVibrate([0, 550, 200, 500])
    .setLights(200, 500, 1000)
    .build();
```

Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help ❤️❤️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for URI of sound file

```
    import * as application from 'tns-core-modules/application';

    const uri = new android.net.Uri.Builder()
        .scheme(android.content.ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE)
        .authority(application.android.nativeApp.getPackageName())
        .appendPath("raw")
        .appendPath("filename")
        .build();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly! It was exactly what I was trying to do!

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to access the content of `raw` folder. Meanwhile you can access in following way.

```
export function createSound(){
    var context = app.android.context;
    var resourcestmp = context.getResources();
    var ident = resourcestmp.getIdentifier("test", "raw", context.getPackageName());
    readFile(ident);
}

function getFDForResource(context, resId) {
    var afd = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(resId);
    if (afd != null) {
       return afd.getFileDescriptor();
    }
    return null;
}

function readFile(resId) {
    var context = app.android.context;
    var fd = getFDForResource(context, resId);
    if(fd != null) {
        var inputStream = new java.io.FileInputStream(fd);
        var nextByte;
        console.log(inputStream);
        while((nextByte = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
            // read here.
        }
    }
}
```

For Further read, you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47532620/nativescript-and-resources-folder-is-there-a-simple-solution/47532987#47532987).

Comment: Hey! Thank you! Although I didn't mark it as correct one, because a bit more "complex" than the other one, it still works. Especially for the MediaPlayer, which accepts a context and a FileDescriptor. Thank you!