# NativeScript android play sound on notification

Tags: nativescript

I'm writing native Android code in a Nativescript Angular app, to display a notification with sound.

I followed the recommendations in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54343283/3944673).

I have a sound file named a.mp3, in the following folder:

[image]

Here is the code to configure the sound of the notification:

```
const uri = new android.net.Uri.Builder()
           .scheme(android.content.ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE)
            .authority(application.android.nativeApp.getPackageName())
            .appendPath("raw")
            .appendPath("a.mp3")
            .build();

        const AudioAttributes = android.media.AudioAttributes;
        const audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
            .build();
```

Here is the code to display a notification:

```
const NOTIFICATION_ID = 234;
    const CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
    const name = "my notifications";
    const Description = "some desc";
    const title = "notif title";
    const message = "This notification has been triggered by me";

    const NotificationManager = android.app.NotificationManager;


    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        const importance = android.app.NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

        const mChannel = new android.app.NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        mChannel.setSound(uri, audioAttributes);
        mChannel.setDescription(Description);
        mChannel.enableLights(true);
        mChannel.setLightColor(android.graphics.Color.RED);
        mChannel.enableVibration(true);
        mChannel.setVibrationPattern([100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400]);
        mChannel.setShowBadge(false);

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }


    ///////// Create an activity on tap (intent)
    const Intent = android.content.Intent;
    const PendingIntent = android.app.PendingIntent;
    const intent = new Intent(context, com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    const pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

    ///////// PRESERVE NAVIGATION ACTIVITY. To start a "regular activity" from your notification, set up
    ///////// the PendingIntent using TaskStackBuilder so that it creates a new back stack as follows.
    ///////// SEE: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html
    const TaskStackBuilder = android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;

    const resultIntent = new Intent(context, com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.class);
    const stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);


    ///////// Creating a notification
    var NotificationCompat = android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
    const builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSound(uri)
        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(message)
        .setStyle(
            new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
            .bigText("By default, the notification's text content is truncated to fit one line. If you want your notification to be longer, you can enable an expandable notification by adding a style template with setStyle(). For example, the following code creates a larger text area:")
            )
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true);

    ///////// Show the notification
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

The notification indeed fires, but the sound file is not played.
Can anyone help to solve this, please?

I also tried using another approach of acquiring the mp3 file, as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49046733/3944673):

```
const uri = android.net.Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/raw/a.mp3");
```

But that didn't help either.

Did I put the 'a.mp3' sound file in the correct folder that is recognized by android?

Thanks

Comment: I also tried using the default ringtone but it didn't work: 
var RingtoneManager = android.media.RingtoneManager;
var uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

Comment: What's your Android OS version on your test device? Did you try with different devices? Also you are setting a sound on channel and notification, did you try removing one, may be the one on channel and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Thank you Manoj, I managed to solve this problem. I'll post an answer to this question soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this. I'm writing answer so that others can learn from this question.

Regarding the question I asked - Did I put the 'a.mp3' sound file in the correct folder that is recognized by android?

[image]

The answer is yes. /App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/raw/ is where the above code will look for the sound file.

**But**, I needed to do 2 modifications:

A_ The code needs to be changed to not include the file extension:

```
const uri = new android.net.Uri.Builder()
  .scheme(android.content.ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE)
  .authority(application.android.nativeApp.getPackageName())
  .appendPath("raw")
  .appendPath("a") // Referring to a.mp3
  .build();
```

and then the sound uri would be used like in the code in the question:

```
const mChannel = new android.app.NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
mChannel.setSound(uri, audioAttributes);
```

or

```
const builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSound(uri)
```

B_ I needed to tell webpack to pack the .mp3 files from /App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/raw/ and put it into the nativescript build. To do this, I had to add `{ from: { glob: "**/*.mp3" } },` to webpack.config.js:

```
// Copy assets to out dir. Add your own globs as needed.
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                { from: { glob: "fonts/**" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.png" } },
                { from: { glob: "**/*.mp3" } },
            ], { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] }),
```

As webpack isn't configured to copy all files from App_Resources automatically. The same is true for any other file extension that you'd use in your project (for example: .jpg files).

More info [here](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-audio/issues/131#issuecomment-495559372) (Q&A on 'nativescript-audio' plugin's git).